# count even numbers and characters in a given array

Tags: c, arrays, count

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int result=0;
void count_even(int*b, int size){
    for (int a = 0; a < size; a++){
        if(b[a] % 2 == 0){
            result++;
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argc[]){
    int data_array_1[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11);
    int data_array_2[] = (2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
    int data_array_2[] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    int result_1 = count_even(data_array_1, 6);
    printf("data_array_1 has%d even numbers\n", result_1);
    int result_2 = count_even(data_array_2, 8);
    printf("data_array_2 has %d even numbers\n", result_2);
    int result_3 = count_even(data_array_3, 11);
    printf("data_array_3 has %d even numbers\n", result_3);
    return 0;
}
```

Expected output:

```
data_array_1 has 0 even numbers.

data_array_2 has 8 even numbers.

data_array_3 has 6 even numbers.
```

I am getting an error when I compile the code which points to `count_even` after `int result_1`, `2` and `3`.

How do I get the expected output?

**Also is there a way in which i could count any character regardless of its type in an array( without knowing its size and without using strlen)?**

**for eg:
data_array[]="hello";
=5**

the code for the second question is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int get_length(char*buffer))
{
int length=0;
length=sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);
return length;
}
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
char string1[] = {'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}, '\0'};
char string2[]= "Hello";
char string3[] ="How long is this string?";
printf("%s" is %d chars long. \n", string1, get_length(string1));
printf("%s" is %d chars long. \n", string2, get_length(string2));
printf("%s" is %d chars long. \n", string3, get_length(string3));
return 0;
}
```

when the position for %d has to be filled, the only answer i am getting is "1".

Comment: Please reedit your question; `count_even` doesn't even return a value.

Comment: 1) Indent your code so that it is more readable 2) If you get errors or warnings, post the **exact** error message

Comment: "*is there a way in which i could count any character regardless of its type in an array( without knowing its size and without using strlen)?*" -- Unclear. Please elaborate. Also, you cannot assign a string to *any* datatype.

Comment: @CoolGuy i have to write the code for a question where ive to print -- char string[]="Hello"; in the form of--- printf"%s is %d chars long.\n", string1, get_length(string1)--- where get_length is a function which gets the length of the string "hello".

Comment: @MO. Use `strlen`. Or just implement its functionality. Count until the NUL-terminator(`'\0'`) and return that value. There are many examples on the web.

Comment: @CoolGuy have a look, ive posted my code above

Comment: @CoolGuy i am not allowed to use strlen....

Comment: The posted code won't compile. Please post the **exact** code always. Also, you are doing it wrong. **You cannot do this with `sizeof`**. Use a loop which breaks when the current character is `'\0'`. Increment `length` from the body of the loop. Then, `return length;` after the loop.

Comment: @CoolGuy it does compile but it only gives me the value "1"

Comment: No, it doesn't. Try compiling the code you've shown here.

Comment: BTW, fix the problem by changing `length=sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(int);` to `while(buffer[length] != '\0') length++;`.

Comment: @CoolGuy i got it, thanks a tonne bro, really appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to return the the number of counts to the caller, e.g.

```
    int count_even(int*b, int size) {
       int count = 0;
       for (int a=0; a<size; a++) {
          if(b[a]%2==0) {
             count ++;
          }
       }
       return count;
    }

...
int count_1 = count_even(data_array_1, 6);
printf("data_array_1 has%d even numbers\n", count_1);
```

Please note that I did **not** try out this. This is more or less pseudo code.

Answer (score 4):

change the method to

```
int count_even(int*b, int size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for (int a=0; a<size; a++)
    {
        if(b[a]%2==0)
            result++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

**Reason of your previous errors**:

1.the return type of your method was void but you were assigning the value to an int. so need to change the return type. also instead of incrementing a global variable use a local variable to count the number.

2.Mismatch of opening-closing braces:

```
 int data_array_2[] = (2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
                ------^
```

Comment: Yoo nobo, y u no add `return` statement in your code?

Comment: @rakeb.void ..are dc .. nice to see you here

Answer (score 0):

int result_1= count_even(data_array_1, 6);

count_even is a function which returns nothing, but in above statement an attempt is made to store the return value of the function count_even to result_1 which is of type int. which is in-correct statement.

Even though the logic for even number seems to be correct, but it is not returned from the function.